# C++ Using serial.printf to retrieve variables from a .txt file

Tags: c++, printf

For an MBED project, I have been writing variables to a .txt file in the following format:
AAA,1
BBB,2
CCC,3
DDD,4
etc.
I want to use serial.printf to retrieve the three letters as a string and the numbers as integers.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%3s",str) != EOF) {
```

gives a result of

```
Entry 1: AAA
Entry 2: ,1
Entry 3: BBB
Entry 4: ,2
```

etc, whilst

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%3s,",str) != EOF) {
```

gives a result of

```
Entry 1: AAA
Entry 2: 1
Entry 3: BBB
Entry 4: 2
```

etc, but then

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%3s,%1s",str1,str2) != EOF) {
```

results in

```
Entry 1: str1: 1, str2: 1
Entry 2: str1: 2, str2: 2
```

etc, and replacing str2 with an integer (properly initialised) results in the second variable being a long number which is the same for each entry, I presume the storage address of the variable.
What code should I use, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I understood your question correctly**

and,
if the data is represented as below

```
AAA,1 BBB,2 CCC,3 DDD,4
```

The following code will be adequate

```
FILE* _in_file_ = fopen("test2.txt","r");

if (!_in_file_)
{
    printf("ERROR::File not found [%s]\n", "test2.txt");
    return 1;
}

char buf[4];
buf[3] = '\0';

long value = 0;
while (fscanf(_in_file_,"%3s,%ld ",buf,&value) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s|%ld\n",buf,value);
}
```